# Im having a problem with reading a file, then assigning it to a struct array and printing it back out

Tags: c

Im currently having to take an input.txt file, where it goes something like

**3**

**Sarah 90 40 30**

**John 23 55 33**

**help 34 99 74**

as an input file,

and read it into a struct array, then create an output.txt.

I seem to be having a problem with the assignment. I tried fscanf, fgetc, fgets, strtok, delim and everything i could find on the internet, but due to my sloppy pointer knowledge, i seem to be stuck.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
typedef struct studentT{
    char *name;
    int literature;
    int math;
    int science;
}studentT;

int main(void)
{
    printf("Start of main\n");

    FILE *fptr;
    int i;
    fptr = fopen("input.txt", "r");

//reading first line to dynamically allocate studentT
    printf("dynamically allocating studentT\n");

    char tempsize[4];
    //fgets(tempsize,1,fptr);
    //i=atoi(&tempsize[0]);
    fscanf(fptr,"%d",&i);
    struct studentT* record = malloc(i*sizeof(*record));

    printf("i has interger value %d\n", i);
//line counter ignoring line 0; reading 1 and 2.

    char line[24];
    char buffer[24];
    char delim[] = " ";

    char *array[4];
    int *darray[4];
    printf("entering while loop\n");

    fgets(buffer,24,fptr);

    int idx =0;

    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line),fptr)!=NULL &&idx<i)
    {

        puts(line);
        char *buf = strtok(line, delim);
        int iter =0;
        while(buf!=NULL)
        {
            if(iter = 0){
                array[iter]=buf;
                buf = strtok(NULL,delim);
            }
            for(iter=1;iter<4;iter++){
            *darray[iter] =atoi(buf);//
            printf("%d,",*darray[iter]);
            buf=strtok(NULL, delim);
            }
        }


            record[idx].name=array[0];
            record[idx].literature=*darray[1];
            record[idx].math=*darray[2];
            record[idx].science=*darray[3];

        //    printf("array value: %s %d %d %d\n",array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3]);
        //    printf("value after casting: %s %zu %zu %zu\n", array[0], (uintptr_t)array[1], (uintptr_t)array[2], (uintptr_t)array[3]);
        //sscanf(buf,"%s %d %d %d",record[idx].name, &record[idx].literature, &record[idx].math, &record[idx].science);
        printf("%s\n", line);

        //fscanf(fptr,"%s %d %d %d",record[idx].name, &record[idx].literature, &record[idx].math, &record[idx].science);
        line[strlen(line)-1]='\0';    
        printf("in idx loop %d %s %d %d %d\n\n", idx, record[idx].name, record[idx].literature, record[idx].math, record[idx].science);
        idx++;
    }

//output of file

    printf("output commencing\n\n\n");
    int tempave;
    FILE *fout;
    char *str1 = "Name Literature Math Science Ave.\n";

    char *str2 = "Ave. ";
    char *str3 = "Sarah\t 96\t 90\t 80\t 88.67";
    char *str4 = "Minsu\t 55\t 70\t 76\t 67.00";
    char *str5 = "Nara\t 88\t 70\t 96\t 84.67";
    char *str6 = "79.67 76.67 84.00 80.11";

    fout = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    fprintf(fout,"%s\n", str1);


    for(int idx=0;idx<i;idx++){
        tempave = (record[idx].math+record[idx].literature+record[idx].science)/3;
        fwrite(&record[idx],sizeof(struct studentT),1,fout);
        fprintf(fout, "%d\n",tempave);
    }

    //fprintf(fout, "%s\n %s\n %s\n %s %s\n",str3,str4,str5,str2,str6); 


    fprintf(fout,"%s",str2);

    float mathave,litave,sciave;

    for(int idx=0;idx<3;idx++){
        mathave+=record[idx].math;
        litave+=record[idx].literature;
        sciave+=record[idx].science;
    }

    mathave=mathave/3;
    sciave=sciave/3;
    litave=litave/3;

    fprintf(fout,"%f %f %f",litave, mathave, sciave);

    fclose(fptr);
    fclose(fout);
}
```

edit: colleague mentioned I should malloc arrays so the code now looks uglier:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
typedef struct studentT{
    char *name;
    int literature;
    int math;
    int science;
}studentT;

int main(void)
{
    printf("Start of main\n");

    FILE *fptr;
    int i;
    fptr = fopen("input.txt", "r");

//reading first line to dynamically allocate studentT
    printf("dynamically allocating studentT\n");

    char tempsize[4];
    //fgets(tempsize,1,fptr);
    //i=atoi(&tempsize[0]);
    fscanf(fptr,"%d",&i);
    struct studentT* record = malloc(i*sizeof(*record));

    printf("i has interger value %d\n", i);
//line counter ignoring line 0; reading 1 and 2.

    char line[24];
    char buffer[24];
    char delim[] = " ";

    char *array[4];
    int darray[4];
    printf("entering while loop\n");

    fgets(buffer,24,fptr);

    int idx =0;

    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line),fptr)!=NULL &&idx<i)
    {

        puts(line);
        char *buf = strtok(line, delim);
        int iter =0;
        while(buf!=NULL)
        {
            if(iter = 0){
                array[iter] = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(buf));
                strcpy(array[iter],buf);
                buf = strtok(NULL,delim);
            }
            for(iter=1;iter<4;iter++){
            darray[iter] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(buf));
            memcpy(&darray[iter],buf,(sizeof(char)*strlen(buf)));//
            buf=strtok(NULL, delim);
            }
        }


            record[idx].name=malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(array[0]));
            strcpy(record[idx].name,array[0]);
            record[idx].literature=darray[1];
            record[idx].math=darray[2];
            record[idx].science=darray[3];

        //    printf("array value: %s %d %d %d\n",array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3]);
        //    printf("value after casting: %s %zu %zu %zu\n", array[0], (uintptr_t)array[1], (uintptr_t)array[2], (uintptr_t)array[3]);
        //sscanf(buf,"%s %d %d %d",record[idx].name, &record[idx].literature, &record[idx].math, &record[idx].science);
        printf("%s\n", line);

        //fscanf(fptr,"%s %d %d %d",record[idx].name, &record[idx].literature, &record[idx].math, &record[idx].science);
        line[strlen(line)-1]='\0';    
        printf("in idx loop %d %s %d %d %d\n\n", idx, record[idx].name, record[idx].literature, record[idx].math, record[idx].science);
        idx++;
    }

//output of file

    printf("output commencing\n\n\n");
    int tempave;
    FILE *fout;
    char *str1 = "Name Literature Math Science Ave.\n";

    char *str2 = "Ave. ";
    char *str3 = "Sarah\t 96\t 90\t 80\t 88.67";
    char *str4 = "Minsu\t 55\t 70\t 76\t 67.00";
    char *str5 = "Nara\t 88\t 70\t 96\t 84.67";
    char *str6 = "79.67 76.67 84.00 80.11";

    fout = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    fprintf(fout,"%s\n", str1);


    for(int idx=0;idx<i;idx++){
        tempave = (record[idx].math+record[idx].literature+record[idx].science)/3;
        fwrite(&record[idx],sizeof(struct studentT),1,fout);
        fprintf(fout, "%d\n",tempave);
    }

    //fprintf(fout, "%s\n %s\n %s\n %s %s\n",str3,str4,str5,str2,str6); 


    fprintf(fout,"%s",str2);

    float mathave,litave,sciave;

    for(int idx=0;idx<3;idx++){
        mathave+=record[idx].math;
        litave+=record[idx].literature;
        sciave+=record[idx].science;
    }

    mathave=mathave/3;
    sciave=sciave/3;
    litave=litave/3;

    fprintf(fout,"%f %f %f",litave, mathave, sciave);

    fclose(fptr);
    fclose(fout);
}
```

Comment: `darray` is an array of pointers, but *where do the pointers actually point?* And does it really *need* to be an array of pointers?

Comment: removing * from darray seems to create a plethora of error chains regarding pointer to int wint conversion..etc...

Comment: Did you remember to remove the dereferencing of the array elements as well, as in e.g. `darray[iter] =atoi(buf)`?

Comment: I have, but when i debug, I get a  segmentation fault in the line `darray[iter] =atoi(buf);` . I asked my colleague and he mentioned i should be malloc'ing every array and strcpy instead of using = operator for strings.. still getting seg fault.

Comment: @Some programmer dude 
I defefrenced everything, tried to malloc everything, 
`darray[iter] = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(buf));`
but then this line gives
**assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast**

Answer (score 0):

I have wrote a new version of what you need with comments. Hopefully, you can understand what is happening and fix your code or you can use this as well. You may need to change the name of the inputfile and outputfile to work with your input file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student {
    char *name;
    int literature;
    int math;
    int science;
};
typedef struct student Student;

int main(void) {

  FILE* inputFile;
  FILE* outputFile;
  int first_read; //check to see if the number of students value was read
  int readNumStudents; //count of how many students are there
  int i; //tracking students struct array
  Student* students; //array of student structs

  readNumStudents = 0;
  first_read = 0;
  i = 0;

  inputFile = fopen("input.txt", "r"); //might have to change to whatever your file name is
  outputFile = fopen("output.txt", "w"); //might have to change to whatever you want the output file name to be

  //checking for null  file pointers 
  if(inputFile == NULL){
    printf("Failed to open input file.\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  if(outputFile == NULL){
    printf("Failed to open output file.\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  //read file until end of file is reached
  while(!feof(inputFile)){

    if (first_read == 0){// check to see if first line was read. if not read, then write the value to readNumStudents variable
      fscanf(inputFile, "%d", &readNumStudents);

      first_read = 1; //set the value to 1. this means that the number of students was read.

      students = (Student*) malloc(sizeof(Student) * readNumStudents);//allocate Student structs for the number of given students fro input file. (ie. 3 structs)

      if(students == NULL){//check for null
          printf("Failed to allocate memory for students.\n");
          break;
      }

      //If not null, then for every struct allocate memory for the name string because its char* not char name[50]
      for(int j = 0; j < readNumStudents; j++){
        students[j].name = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * 50);

        if(students[j].name == NULL){//check for null
          printf("Failed to allocate memory for name.\n");
          exit(1);
        }
      }
    } else {//this means that the first line was read. now read the names and scors
        //since you know the format of the input file (string int int int) you can use fscanf with "%s %d %d %d" and the adress of the struct values
        fscanf(inputFile, "%s %d %d %d",  students[i].name, &(students[i].literature), &(students[i].math), &(students[i].science));

        i++;//used to point to next student structure
      }
    }

    //Go thorugh every struct and write each value to outputfile
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
      fprintf(outputFile, "%s %d %d %d\n", students[j].name, (students[j].literature), (students[j].math), (students[j].science));
    }

    //free all the allocated memory and files
    fclose(inputFile);
    fclose(outputFile);
    //you need to free the char array on top of the studnets struct array. so loop through every student to free it
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
      free(students[j].name);
    }
    free(students);

  return 0;
}
```